# Switching StoryBoards (iphone/iPad) without code?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, storyboard

Currently I do it this way

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
     ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)?
                                @"Main_iPad" : @"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
```

But I would love to do it just like a UIImage:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
```

And then leave it up to `XCode` to determine where to look using the suffix.

Is that possible? if so how? if not why ?

Comment: If you're just using a single storyboard (per form factor) you can just set it in the Info.plist.  Select your app in the project file, select your app in targets, select general tab, under deployment info you can change the main interface by switching the devices popup.

Comment: @David I did not understand your suggestion, I have 2 storyboard, I dont want to do the check. I want xCode to look up the suffix just like a `@2x.png`

Comment: AFAIK, you can use the suffix `~ipad` and `~iphone` for nib file names, but not for storyboards. I don't think there's a good reason for that omission.

Comment: Start with a Universal project. Then the appropriate storyboard will be loaded automatically.

Comment: it is a universal app, I use this line of code to present Views modally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those _iPad and _iPhone suffixes are simple identifiers that can be changed in anything you like when you create a new storyboard and they're not related to the @2x stuff (or Image assets as well).
However, if you make large use of different storyboard (to keep their editing simpler and smoother and their version control merge safer), you can write a category on UIStoryboard and write your own logic in one place with a method like

```
+ (UIStoryboard*) appropriateStoryboardWithName:(NSString*) name bundle:(NSBundle*) bundle             
{
    name = [name stringByAppendingString:
    ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) ? @"_iPad" : @"_iPhone"];
    return [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:name bundle:bundle];
}
```

Comment: so basically what I wanted to achieve is not really possible right?

Answer (score 1):

if you want that x-code decides which storyboard load you need to open your info.plist and
specify which storyboard should use for iPad and iphone.

find the row with the KEY - Main storyboard file base name.

Your info.plist must have this two rows

```
KEY                                       TYPE       VALUE

Main storyboard file base name (iPad)    String     Main_iPad
Main storyboard file base name (iPhone)  String     Main_iPhone
```

Now every time your app starts x-code will decide which storyboard load without code

Hope it helps

Good Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing all that code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
     ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)?
                                @"Main_iPad" : @"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
```

Xcode can load the right storyboard if you call `self.storyboard`.

So you use it directly, for example:

```
someViewController *pieVC = [self.storyboard 
                             instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someView"];
```